# What replaces MongoDB AggregationOutput class?

Tags: java, mongodb

All of the methods have being deprecated but I havn't been able to find the replacement class for aggregation with the java driver.

Comment: The result will become a cursor (DBCursor) instead

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to evanchooly answer, here is what to do.
Replace:

```
 AggregationOutput output = collection.aggregate(pipe);
 for (DBObject obj : output.results()) {
     //...
 }
```

by

```
  // this build of options is taken from the original method
  // aggregate(pipe) to have same behaviour
  AggregationOptions options = AggregationOptions.builder()
            .outputMode(AggregationOptions.OutputMode.INLINE)
            .build();

  Cursor cursor = collection.aggregate(pipe,options); 
  while (cursor.hasNext() ) {
      DBObject obj = cursor.next();
      //...
  }
```

Comment: .outputMode(AggregationOptions.OutputMode.INLINE) is also deprecated.

Comment: I'm not working with MongoDB any more, it was 4 years ago ;)
Feel free to give a more up-to-date answer if this one is now deprecated !

Comment: seems right, this is deprecated :(
http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.10/javadoc/com/mongodb/AggregationOptions.Builder.html

Answer (score 3):

I was also facing the same issues and after scanning the MongoAPI docs, I got confused even more, but found an alternative for AggregationOutput class after going through various sites and documentation and some experimentation.

**Initial Code**

```
List<DBObject> studentAggregationQuery = new ArrayList<>();
studentAggregationQuery.add(new BasicDBObject("$roll", roll));
studentAggregationQuery.add(new BasicDBObject("$marks", marks));

AggregationOutput studentOutput = collection.aggregate(studentAggregationQuery);

List<StudentData> studentDataList = new ArrayList<>();
studentOutput.results().forEach(dbObject -> {
    orderMetricsList.add(new 
    StudentData(mongoTemplate.getConverter().read(Students.class, 
            (Integer) dbObject.get("roll"), (Double) dbObject.get("marks")));
});
```

So the DBObject class is also deprecated, I had to replace it with Document class. You can read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44878605/mongodb-basicdbobject-vs-document-in-java). And I have used [AggregateIterable](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.6/javadoc/com/mongodb/client/AggregateIterable.html) interface with [MongoCursor](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.7/javadoc/com/mongodb/client/MongoCursor.html) and that did the trick.

**Final Code**

```
List<Document> studentAggregationQuery = new ArrayList<>();
studentAggregationQuery.add(new Document("$roll", roll));
studentAggregationQuery.add(new Document("$marks", marks));

AggregateIterable studentDataIterator = 
collection.aggregate(studentAggregationQuery);

List<StudentData> studentDataList = new ArrayList<>();
MongoCursor<Document> studentIterator = studentDataIterator.iterator();
while (studentIterator.hasNext()) {
    Document next = studentIterator.next();
    studentDataList.add(new 
    StudentData(mongoTemplate.getConverter().read(Students.class,
        (Integer) next.get("roll"), (Double) next.get("marks")));
}
```

I hope you would be able to replace AggregationOutput with AggregateIterable to get the desired output/results.

Comment: The mongo documentation is not clear. AggregateIterable interface worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at [DBCollection](http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/com/mongodb/DBCollection.html) you'll see several variants of `aggregate()` including those that return `AggregationOutput`.  The preferred version is to use the variants that take `AggregationOptions` and return a `Cursor`, however.  This allows you to configure a number of [options](http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/com/mongodb/AggregationOptions.html) but most importantly, the ability to use a cursor for the response for cases where the aggregated results would break the 16M document size limit.  If you were to use $out in your pipeline, this would be the preferred method as well since it would let you immediately start iterating over the collection you just populated.

Answer (score 0):

**[MongoAPI Docs](http://api.mongodb.org/java/current/com/mongodb/AggregationOutput.html)** has no clue about which class has replaced AggregationOutput.

But as of the functionality, `AggregationOutput` class was used to store the result set of a mongo query. And object of `aggregationOutput.results()` will provide an array of documents which you can iterate using an iterator to get the individual docs.

So `DBCursor` is the close match in that case.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of how you must use aggregata. my function in Java

```
 /**
 * MongoDB Code:
 * db.review_Rating.aggregate([
 * { $match : { media_id:"456" } },
 * { $group:{ _id:"$media_id", avg_rating:{ $avg : "$rating" } } } ] )
 *
 * @param mediaID that is being sought
 * @return Float arage rating for the media with param mediaID,
 * if not found return null
 */
Float getAvrageRating(String mediaID) {

    DBCollection collection = getConnection("MongoMedia", "review_Rating");

    if(mediaID != null) {
        LinkedList<DBObject> pipe = new LinkedList<>();
        pipe.add(new BasicDBObject("media_id", mediaID));

        DBObject groupFields = new BasicDBObject("media_id", mediaID);
        groupFields.put("avg_rating", new BasicDBObject("$avg", "$rating"));
        pipe.add(new BasicDBObject("$group", groupFields));
        AggregationOutput cursor = collection.aggregate(pipe);

        LinkedList<String> values = new LinkedList<>();
        for (DBObject doc : cursor.results()) {
            JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(doc.toString());
            values.add(obj.getString("avg_rating"));

            JSONObject idObj = (JSONObject) obj.get("_id");
            values.add((String) idObj.get("$oid"));
        }
        return Float.valueOf(values.getFirst());
    }
    return null;

}
```